# Getting a 'Rule' object is not iterable when using scrapy CrawlSpider

Tags: scrapy, anaconda

I have been trying to crawl a series of pages, that are linked from a source page, but failing, below is my spider.py file

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class DogstatsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dogstats"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ukdogracing.net"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ukdogracing.net/todays-runners/"]
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='runners'), callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        
        yield {
            'dogtime' : "test"
        }
```

When I crawl this I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable

to add more detail, all the href links that I want are specified in css format of

> href="/runners/*"

I note that the full link would be

> http://www.ukdogracing.net/runners/*
> as listed in
> http://www.ukdogracing.net/todays-runners/

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update, I have found the answer, I should have been using [] not () for rules =

strange the tutorial I was following on youtube used () and it worked, but not for my spider, however I changed mine to [] and it is now working.